# Multiple-framework .NET Core Library (VS2015 update3)

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm trying to create a simple .NET Core library using VS2015 Update 3, but I find it difficult to locate up-to-date documentation about some details.

This library should be consumed by both .NET Core Libraries and traditional "full" .NET 4.6.2 libraries and/or desktop applications (console/WPF).

To this end, the relevant parts of project.json for the library are like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
},
"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.5": {
    "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "dotnet4.6.2" ]
   },
   "net462": {
     "frameworkAssemblies": {
       "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0",
       "System.Xml.Linq": "4.0.0.0"
    }
}
```

Here I downgraded the `netstandard` from 1.6 to 1.5 to allow for .NET 4.6.2 compatibility, and (this could probably be avoided) added dotnet4.6.2 to `imports`.

AFAIK, to consume this library I essentially have these options:

- I can directly reference its project from whithin the same solution, e.g. when creating a .NET Core Library for testing (e.g. for the xUnit test library see https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html).
- I can pack the library into a NuGet, add it to a local NuGet feed (https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) and then consume it as any other NuGet package. To pack the library I just have to type `dotnet pack` under the same directory of `project.json`; I can then install the generated package into my local feed, and consume it.

Anyway, it seems that even if I specified `net462` as a framework, when I try to import the generated package I get an error telling me that:

```
Package ... is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package ... supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
```

Yet, my package seems to correctly list the groups in its nuspec (I can rename the generated .nupkg to .zip and inspect its contents), e.g.:

```
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6.2">
    <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="[1.6.0, )" />
  </group>
  <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.5">
    <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="[1.6.0, )" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
<frameworkAssemblies>
  <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6.2" />
  <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml.Linq" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6.2" />
</frameworkAssemblies>
```

Thus I suppose I missed something in creating the library or its package. I know this is all rather new, but could anyone confirm or correct my assumptions above, and explain how I can consume a .NET Core Library from multiple platforms?

Comment: For my own library ([this one](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths)), I did a "port" to .NET Standard some days ago and ended up providing two NuGet packages (one for .NET 4.x, one for .NET Core). On the other hand, your solution looks much more elegant if it works.

Comment: I have probably found a solution: it seems that even if I had removed and recreated the local NuGet feed, something had been left somewhere in a cache, so that my changes to the .NET Core lib were not picked up by the consumer code. I increased the version number of my modified lib and it worked. Still, any other experience or suggestion in this new environment is welcome.

Comment: I must add that according to my findings referencing a .NET core lib from another .NET core lib used to test it in the same solution does not always work. Especially when the tested lib imports packages of other similar libraries, I cannot compile, as if I had imported nothing. Yet the import is in place without errors. Tried to import the DLL from the bin folder directly, but nothing changes.